# Ruby creates HMAC signature which contains several elements

Tags: ruby, authentication, hmac

In my pure Ruby app one of the components to create a token for my request authentication to an external API is to create `signature` which is HMAC value that is created using the `api_key` and the `secret_key`. The signature contains the following elements that are each separated by a new line `\n` (except the last line) and are in the same order as below list:

```
  ts = '1529342939277'
  nonce = '883b170c-a768-41a1-ae6d-c626323aa128'
  host = 'ws.idms.lexisnexis.com'
  resource_path = '/restws/identity/v3/accounts/11111/workflows/rdp.test.workflow/conversations'
  body_hash = 'fQoIAs0IO4vNleZVE9tcI3Ni7h+niT+GrrgEHsKZOyM='

  API_KEY = '6njQLkz7uCiz1ZeJ1bFCWX4DFVTfKQXa'
  SECRET_KEY = 'CcdaZEt7co647iJoEc5G29CHtlo7T9M3'
  # create string signature separated by new line
  signature = [ts, nonce, host, resource_path, body_hash].join("\n")
  # create HMAC for signature
  mac = Base64.strict_encode64(OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest('SHA256', API_KEY, signature))

2.7.0 :146 > mac
 => "ZDE4NDQxZDdiNmZkODNiODgyODI4Nzc2OTQ3OGFlMjVhZTMyNThhZTZlMTRiMjkxMzI0NmQ5NzljNDJkZWVhZg=="
```

According to the docs the signature should be `Syb6i+sRygAGCgxLQJ4NwwKcT5Mnkh4r3QXgwZ3vmcE=` but I'm getting `ZDE4NDQxZDdiNmZkODNiODgyODI4Nzc2OTQ3OGFlMjVhZTMyNThhZTZlMTRiMjkxMzI0NmQ5NzljNDJkZWVhZg==` instead. Where did I go wrong?

I've got an example how to do it in Java if something will be unclear: https://gist.github.com/mrmuscle1234/20c9d46d163fee66528449c0ea8419a7

Comment: In your code you have `KEY_ID` and `SECRET_KEY`, neither of which are used, and then `API_KEY` in the HMAC call, which isn’t defined. You are also using `hexdigest` instead of `digest`, but I don’t think that alone is why you are getting the wrong answer.

Comment: @matt my mistake - `KEY_ID == API_KEY`, question updated. If I'll use `digest` the result will be `0YRB17b9g7iCgod2lHiuJa4yWK5uFLKRMkbZecQt7q8=`

Comment: *"According to the docs"* What docs? Please provide the docs. Additionally your Java example leaves out a substantial number of pertinent details that would prevent it from being ported to ruby

Comment: @engineersmnky The documentation provides an example like the one I described above. It shows that I should get an HMAC == `Syb6i+sRygAGCgxLQJ4NwwKcT5Mnkh4r3QXgwZ3vmcE`. They also give an example how to implement token creation in JAVA (this HMAC is a part of that functionality). Here is the gist with full class functionality - https://gist.github.com/mrmuscle1234/881144360e13ac1ac1794610c456d035